# mysql set null if variable not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to do a simple mysql update command:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `myTable` SET `rowA` = '".$varA ?? NULL."'
WHERE `id` = '1'";
```

If $varA has an value, take this, if not => NULL
But with echo $sql it looks like this:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `rowA` =
```

An idea?

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: By the way, `$varA ?? NULL` **does exactly the same than just** `$varA`

Comment: The reason it behaves like this, is [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `.` has a higher one than `??`, so what you have written there, is effectively the same as `("... SET rowA = '".$varA) ?? NULL`

Comment: yes but I need the "NULL" for the mysql statement

Comment: @CBroe and how can I fix this?

Comment: *"how can I fix this"* Once again, Use prepared statements.

Comment: The "fix" for the issue in general would be to introduce explicit braces around the parts you want handled with "higher priority", than they would normally have. `"UPDATE myTable SET rowA = '".($varA ?? NULL)."'` The result would _still_ be wrong of course, because now you would be setting the _text_ `NULL`, due to the fact that it is wrapped in single quotes. Those would need to go around the $var value only. So, please use prepared statements already ...

Comment: If `$varA` is set you must insert `'$varA'`. If it is not set you must insert `NULL` - without single quotes! With quote chars you'd insert not `NULL` (unknown value in SQL) but 4-symbol string `'NULL'`.

Answer (score 1):

With prepared statement:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `myTable` SET `rowA` = ? WHERE `id` = ?;');

// Values to bind
$valueRowA = $varA ?? null;   // assuming $varA is a string or null
$valueId = 1;                 // assuming an int

// Bind the values to the SQL statement
$stmt->bind_param('si', $valueRowA, $valueId);
// 'si' tells bind_param() that $valueRowA is a string and $valueId is an int

// Execute the query
$stmt->execute();
```